# Using Django, how do I set a ModelForm field value dynamically in the template?

Tags: forms, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to utilize a checkbox field to create a model instance for a user selected favorite. The last piece I need in order for this to work properly is to set the default value in one of the form fields equal to the value in a loop. Would I do this with the initialize argument, in the views.py file, in the form itself, or in the template? Here is the associated code:
*Apologies for the HTML class tags*

models.py

```
class ReportDirectory(models.Model):
    report_name = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True, blank=False)
    report_desc = models.TextField()
    report_type = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    report_loc = models.TextField()
    slug =  models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=300)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    main_tags = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    
    # Renames the item in the admin folder
    def __str__(self):
        return self.report_name

class Favorite(models.Model):
    directory_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_report = models.ForeignKey(ReportDirectory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    favorited = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.directory_user)+" - "+str(self.user_report)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Favorite

class FavoriteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Favorite
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'favorited': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={
                'type':'checkbox',
                'name':'checkbox',
                'onchange':'submit()'
            })
        }
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.views import generic
from .models import ReportDirectory, Favorite
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .forms import FavoriteForm


def report_directory(request):
    favorite = Favorite.objects.filter(directory_user=request.user.id, favorited=True)
    reports = ReportDirectory.objects.exclude(favorite__directory_user=request.user.id, favorite__favorited=True)
    
    favform = FavoriteForm(initial={'directory_user':request.user},)
    
    context = {
        'reports':reports,
        'favorite':favorite,
        'favform':favform
    }

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FavoriteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/report_directory')

    return render(request, 'counter/report_directory.html',context)
```

html

```
<thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="gls-table-expand">Favorite</th>
                            <th onclick="sortTable(1)" class="gls-table-expand">Report Type</th>
                            <th onclick="sortTable(2)" class="gls-table-expand">Report Name</th>
                            <th class="gls-table-expand">Report Description</th>
                            <th onclick="sortTable(3)" class="gls-table-expand">Last Updated</th>
                            <th class="gls-table-expand">Main Tags</th>
                            <th onclick="sortTable(4)" class="gls-table-expand">View Count</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="myTable">
                        {% for r in reports.all %}                            
                            <tr report-name="{{ r.report_name }}">
                                <td>  
                                    <form method="POST">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        {{ favform.favorited }}
                                    </form> 
                                </td>
                                <td><span><img img width="20" height="20" 
                                    {% if r.report_type == 'Tableau' %}
                                        src=" {% static 'images/tableau_icon.svg' %}"
                                    {% elif r.report_type == 'Excel' %}
                                        src=" {% static 'images/excel_icon.svg' %}"
                                    {% elif r.report_type == 'Box' %}
                                        src=" {% static 'images/excel_icon.svg' %}"
                                    {% elif r.report_type == 'Internal Report' %}
                                        src=" {% static 'images/www_icon.svg' %}"
                                    {% endif %}
                                        ></span> {{ r.report_type }}</td>
                                <td><a href="{% url 'report_shell' r.slug %}">{{ r.report_name }}</a></td>
                                <td>{{ r.summary }}</td>
                                <td><p class="gls-text-meta gls-margin-remove-top">{{ r.last_update_format }}</p></td>
                                <td>{{ r.main_tags }}</td>
                                <td>{% get_hit_count for r %}</td>
                            </tr>             
                        {% endfor %} 
                    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to dynamically iterate through the template and complete the ForeignKey (selection) field. I needed to set the for iterator equal to the selection option

```
<form method="POST" id="{{ r.report_name }}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p hidden>
        {{ favform.directory_user }}
        <select name="user_report" required="" id="id_user_report">
           <option value="{{ r.id }}" selected></option>
        </select>
    </p>
    {{ favform.favorited }}
</form>
```

I feel like I'm working against Django forms, however, and not with the infrastructure...